# qtaguid: Untagging socket 64 failed errno=-22

Tags: android, android-volley, odoo-9

I am creating one event from android app and uploading those event data on server using web service. Here for web service, I am using Volley lib.

The event data uploading is working fine on server but I didn't get any response on volley library and due to that app is getting hang or facing response timeout problem.

I have checked the app side log and found below error

> qtaguid: Untagging socket 64 failed errno=-22
>   NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(64) failed with errno -22

Here is my code for calling web services

```
  JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, postData, requestFuture, requestFuture);
  request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(new_request_timeout, new_request_max_retry, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
  requestQueue.add(request);
```

Here new_request_timeout = 60000 and new_request_max_try = 1 that I set dynamically for every event

Is there anyone have idea about this error ?